# Any Automocking frameworks that generate from actual data in database

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

Does anything described below exist?

Hi, I'm a c# and javascript programmer. When creating tests the pain point for me is the creation of the test dependencies.  Especially when I am making assertions against values that I expect in the database.

I know that writing tests that make calls to the database is a bad practice since many database calls can slow down the entire test suite.  The alternative is we as developers must create these large sometimes complicated mock objects that contain the values that the database would otherwise be returning.

Instead I would like to create my tests against an actual database.  Then I would like for my test running application or testing framework to make note of the object returned from the database.  The testing framework would replace the dependency on the database with an automatically created stub object for all subsequent runs of this test.

Essentially the database would only get hit the very first time a test is run and from that point forward it would instead use that data it retrieved from the first pass of the test as the stub or mock object.

This would entirely mitigate the need to ever manually create an object for the purpose of testing.

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer your question, most service virtualization frameworks support this.

Comment: There are more alternatives than that: you can create an in-memory database for each test or you empty/delete the database after each test and fill/create it before the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) to create the data.

It does have *some* support for data annotations, but you'd probably still need to tweak it extensively to fit your particular database schema.